# Move all files NOT ending with .txt

Tags: bash, grep, find, filenames, xargs

In the directory `/home/username/data` I have both files and directories. Some of these filenames end in `.txt` (to which I'll refer as *text files*), others don't. The same happens in the subdirectories.

One of the subdirectories is called `other_files` (its full path is `/home/username/data/other_files/`).

I'd like to move all the files not ending with `.txt` *in the root of* `/home/username/data` to `other_files`.

---

I could possibly do it with a loop, but that's not what I want. I want to use commands and piping. I believe this is easy, I'm just not seeing it. A combination of `mv`, `find`, `grep` and `xargs` should do it, I'm just not sure how.

So I'm stuck in trying to match the text files (to then think of way to match everything except them). In the following, assume my current directory is `/home/username/data`.
First I went for `find . | grep -E "*\.txt"`, but this matches all text files, including the ones in the subdirectories.
So I tried `find . | grep -E "\./*\.txt"` just to see if I would get the same matches to then work my way towards my goal, but this doesn't match anything and this is where I'm stuck.

---

How do I go about doing what I described at the beginning of the question?

Comment: so you would like to move all files which are not ending with `.txt` from currunt directory `/home/username/data` to its sub-directory `/home/username/data/other_files`'.... am i right?

Comment: `find DIR \! -name '*.txt'` might help. Also can you add an example of source and target structure? Right now it's not clear whether the other directories beneath `/home/username/data` need to be recreated beneath `/home/username/data/other_files/`.

Comment: @msp9011 You're correct.

Comment: @nohillside They don't need to be recreated within `other_files` because I only want to move files that are directly on the root of `home/username/data`.

Comment: some greps have a -v flag that negates the results of the regex

Comment: when doing `find -exec xyz` to do an action on a lot of files, change it to find `-exec echo xyz` so you can see what commands are being generated. You can pipe this to a file to inspect by eye, or to `more`, and when happy you can run said file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple shell loop variant (in `bash`):

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob nullglob

for pathname in ~username/data/!(*.txt); do
    ! test -d "$pathname" && mv "$pathname" ~username/data/other_files
done
```

The shell options set on the first line will make the `bash` shell enable extended globbing patterns (`!(*.txt)` to match all names not ending with `.txt`), it enables glob patterns to match hidden names, and it makes the pattern expand to nothing at all if nothing matches.

The body of the loop will skip anything that is a directory (or symbolic link to a directory) and will move everything else to the given directory.

The equivalent thing with `find` and GNU `mv` (will move symbolic links to directories if there are any, and will invoke `mv` for as many files as possible at a time, but those are the only differences):

```
find ~username/data -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name '*.txt' \
    -exec mv -t ~username/data/other_files {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: In your second solution you're not accounting for `*.txt`, are you?

Comment: @MovingMan Fixed it as you were typing your comment ;-)

Comment: Side question, do you know why the regex I mentioned (`find . | grep -E "\./*\.txt"`) failed?

Comment: @MovingMan It assumes that the pathnames look like `./.txt` where the `/` is allowed to be repeated, as in `./////.txt`.  Use regular expressions on _text_ and use filename globbing patterns (and not `grep`) on filenames.

Answer (score 7):

```
find /home/username/data -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} /home/username/data/other_files/ \;
```

- maxdepth limits to the top directors
- type ensures that only files are found, not directories

Comment: You'd better use `-type f` or it will try to move `other_files`, and any other subdirectory of `data` that we don't know about.

Comment: @Kusalananda is correct, I'm going to need that.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the behavior of `-exec mv {} /home/username/data/other_files/ \;`. How is it that this moves from the current directory to `other_files`? The syntax for move, usually, is `mv source directory`.

Comment: @MovingMan The `{}` will replaced by the current pathname that `find` is looking at.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh! That was my first guess, but then what is the meaning of `\;`? That's what led me to discard that very plausible interpretation.

Comment: @MovingMan `-exec` takes a utility and arguments. To know where that command line ends, `find` looks for `;`.  The `;` needs to be escaped to protect it from the shell.

Comment: just realized that the bash solution doesn’t work...

Comment: @nohillside No, it also copies the `other_files` directory.

Answer (score 2):

This code should move all files not ending in ".txt" to your target folder, however if you happen to have files with the same name in different paths it will throw an error.

```
find /home/username/data ! -name "*.txt" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} /home/username/data/other_files/ \;
```

Comment: Doesn‘t this also try to move the files put into `other_files` again?

Comment: I think it will simply throw an error that the source and target is the same. Only case where this could be bad is if `other_files` has a directory structure that should not be touched. In this case this could be excluded from the find command with `! -path`.

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` to stop it from walking down into subdirectories.

Comment: Kusalananda is correct.

Comment: Can you please check my comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492006/move-all-files-not-ending-with-txt#comment903059_492012)?

Answer (score 1):

The following line finds all files and hidden files in the current directory that are not `*.txt` and not a path and move them into newpath:

`ls -1p | grep -v "^.*\.txt$" | grep -v ".*/$" | xargs mv -vt newpath`

The following is the same but moves also hidden files:

`ls -1ap | grep -v "^.*\.txt$" | grep -v ".*/$" | xargs mv -vt newpath`

**Both command lines don't scan directories recursively and don't move directories**

If you have filenames that contains spaces you may use:

`ls -1ap | grep -v "^.*\.txt$" | grep -v ".*/$" | xargs -d'\n' printf "\"%s\"\n" | xargs mv -vt newpath`

Comment: This might have a problem with files whose names contain a space.

Comment: Is true. But also using find we've the same issue. Have you an indication to solve this issue without using scripts?.

Comment: This isn't an issue for find (use `-exec ... {}` or `-print0 | xargs -0 ...`). The problem can't be solved for text/pipe based shell constructs though (at least not with reasonable effort and complexity)

Comment: I mean the issue in my command line.

Comment: The problem can't be solved for text/pipe based shell constructs like yours (at least not with reasonable effort and complexity)

Comment: I think the edit I've added to my answer may solve this issue.

Comment: Nice. Did you try with file names containing \n as well? Sorry to be a nuisance here, but there are so many special cases to cover that it's usually just not worth the effort. It might be an interesting intellectual challenge though :-)